# 'buildozer android debug deploy run' gives error

Tags: python, kivy

I am using kivy to build an app. I am following [these](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html) instructions to create a package for Android using Buildozer. But when I run :

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

I get the following error:

```
Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory /home/username/buildozer/.buildozer
# Create directory /home/username/buildozer/bin
# Create directory /home/username/buildozer/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /home/username/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform
# Create directory /home/username/buildozer/.buildozer/android/app
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/username/anaconda3/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git clone -b master --single-branch https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android'
# Cwd /home/username/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform
Cloning into 'python-for-android'...
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q  \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/username/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19b
# Android NDK found at /home/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b
# Installing/updating SDK platform tools if necessary
# Run '/home/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools'
# Cwd /home/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
# Command failed: /home/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CONDA_SHLVL = '1'
#     GS_LIB = '/home/username/.fonts'
#     KDE_FULL_SESSION = 'true'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'                                                                                                   
#     CONDA_EXE = '/home/username/anaconda3/bin/conda'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     LANG = 'en_IN'
#     PROFILEHOME = ''
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/username'
#     SHELL_SESSION_ID = '4f22997e821248a2a35f4f8f7807f1da'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     CONDA_PREFIX = '/home/username/anaconda3'
#     XDG_VTNR = '1'
#     PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN = '/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-hdYrDsPL4tiM/agent.1490'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/plasma.mandatory.path'
#     _CE_M = ''
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '3'
#     USER = 'username'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'plasma'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/plasma.default.path'
#     PWD = '/home/username/buildozer'
#     HOME = '/home/username'
#     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE = '/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1564'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/plasma:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     _CE_CONDA = ''
#     KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION = '/Sessions/1'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'KDE'
#     KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW = '/Windows/1'
#     CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER = '(base) '
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE = ':1.58'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     XCURSOR_THEME = 'breeze_cursors'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'KDE'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     KONSOLE_PROFILE_NAME = 'Default'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     COLORFGBG = '15;0'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
#     WINDOWID = '50331654'
#     LOGNAME = 'username'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     PAM_KWALLET_LOGIN = '/run/user/1000/kwallet.socket'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/username/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1'
#     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '0'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-plasma:/etc/xdg:/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kf5-settings'
#     PATH = '/home/username/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/username/anaconda3/bin:/home/username/anaconda3/condabin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/username/.local/bin'                                                                       
#     KDE_SESSION_UID = '1000'
#     KDE_SESSION_VERSION = '5'
#     CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV = 'base'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/username:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1665,unix/username:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1665'                                                                                                             
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I don't know how to check the log. Where can I find them? I am fairly new to all this so I don't think I will be able to find the error even if I read them.

Comment: The log is the output of th ebuildozer command. Please post all of it.

Comment: By buildozer command you mean this 'buildozer android debug deploy run'?

Comment: run this command to see the dialog `buildozer -v android debug`

Comment: @PabloGod I am getting the same error when I run that

Comment: @inclement I posted  all of the output. Please review it...

Comment: Can you show me what this command output shows `java -version`

Comment: @PabloGod openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Install openjdk 8

Comment: For Buildozer you need to install java8 and set as default in your pc

Comment: Thanks for replying everyone. I realized that I missed the 'install dependencies' step for Buildozer. I did that and now everything is working fine.